# Videos loading slow on mobile

Tags: html, video, mp4

I have a website with mp4 videos and jpg posters but the vids load pretty slow on mobile anyway of speeding that up? iv renamed the file names but here is my code:

```html
<div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin-bottom:128px">
  <div class="w3-half w3-center">
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-half w3-center">
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/image.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="w3-right">
      <a title="Next" href="page-2.html" class="w3-button border">Next</a>
      <a style="margin-right: 100px;" href="page-2.html" class="w3-button border">2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only way to improve the load speed for mobile would be to shrink the quality for mobile, or get better connection.

Comment: @Sean it's possibly a metadata issue. If placed at the end of your file then all other bytes must be downloaded to reach the meta. It is required by MPEG decoders to play MP4 video correctly. Do you have one of your MP4 files also saved on disk? If yes, open it with a [**hex editor**](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/) to see the file bytes.  If you see the word `mdat` first instead of seeing `moov` first within beginning 5 lines or so that means your metadata is at the back/ending of total file bytes. It must be moved to front via some editor tool. Search `fix mp4 moov to front`...

Comment: @sean Got a link to one slow mp4? This a classic MP4 problem. If metadata is at front then video can play sooner (or immediately shows picture) since the meta tells all players **where in file bytes** is the **actual** video frames and audio frames etc.. If it's too complicated to do a basic check and fix with some free tool then I feel sorry for such web developer and their customers or end users.

Comment: My vids are located at https://thg-graphics.com/portfolio.html you can test them on mobile. they have posters as jpgs, they also are alllll under 10mb. now i cant shrink them down into kbs or they will look terrible.... because its a portfolio i want my work to look good. plus i dont wanna use youtube cos it can override my javascript to disable right click. i wanna protect my graphics the best i can.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Try adding`preload="none"` as the **last** parameter in your `<video>` tag setup.

```
<video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/thg.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
<source src="videos/Comp 1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The problem is all your videos on the page try to buffer/load all at once, slowing everything down. Using *preload="none"* will stop any preload until user chooses to play (they will load faster).

Another thing might be that you just have a slow server. One video file was only 500-odd KB but still buffered in small chunks. On my internet, I expect 500 KB data to be fully loaded in an instant.

Check if your server provider is somehow limiting or throttling any speed/size of sent packets whenever a file request is made.

(2) Don't use **spaces** / quotes / colons / brackets etc... in a web URL!!! 
 
Whilst some browsers might be fixing this for you (spaces in the link/URL is edited to become as `%20`), there is still no guarantee another app will accept `vid 1.mp4` unless you remember to request the file as `vid%201.mp4`. Use underscore `vid_1.mp4` or dash `vid-1.mp4` or simply no space as `vid1.mp4`.

Comment: where did i have vid 1.mp4?  spaces dont work for most things like this as for why i dont have them in anything... if i did please show me where so i can fix it. also iv added the preload="none" in each one as shown above in your post in hopes it loads faster. though i figured something out... they buffer when clicking play and they dont buffer half and play they buffer fully then play thats why its slow on mobile....

Comment: Look at the source code of your portfolio HTML for any mistakes. Video tags number 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8 all have file names with spaces. See their `src` parameter. PS: I had tested on desktop not mobile and the videos loaded slow. Why does a small few KB video of few second duration stops at least 5 times, for each stop it spends around 3 seconds buffering a small part? This is why I suspect your server.

Comment: There are no spaces? i dont understand? please point out where ? im confused? i have no spaces so where are you saying there are?

Comment: if you wanna look heres the page that was slow on mobile and its cos it buffers fully b4 playing them. https://thg-graphics.com/portfolio.htm

Comment: look at the code of your first video tag `<source src="videos/Comp 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">`. Now right-click **src** link and open in new tab you'll see its URL is `Comp%201.mp4`. I know the problem is trying to fully buffer multiple videos whilst all loading from slow/throttled server, I told you that analysis in my Answer above. Your next thought should be to test an alternate location for one video file to see if speed is better. Your files themselves seem fine (metadata is at front, has supported codec settings), so could be server issue...

Comment: should now be fixed up.

Comment: `preload="none"` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Alex01 Other factors might be affecting the loading speed.. Do you have a testable link to one of your slow loading video for checking? If it is loading an incoming stream of bytes (instead of loading a stored file) and that stream does not provide metadata as first bytes received then it might also be slow.